# How to know if site collection is root with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I want to loop over all web application's site collection and activate a feature on root web except the root site collection. How to know if current site collection is the root one.

PS : I've used to compare site collection url with web application url but this isn't the best practice for me.

```
...
if($site.Url -like $WebAppUrl)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code. But, Go for something like $site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url . Basically, the root site collection is the first item in 'Sites' collection.

Hope its clear :)

Comment: Yeah it's clear thanks. I already thought about this option, but I don't love indexed properties. I'm looking for something more generic and with the least risk of change and errors.